# Rails 4 ActiveRecord has many through relationship not working from sql file read

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am currently working on a project where I have to populate a `postgresql` the database from an existing `.sql` file and then seeding the database using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read("path/to/file.sql"))`

This creates many tables and join tables, they do not have migrations associated with them.

When I create the ActiveRecord models to go along with the DB all goes well until I am trying to set up relationships through a couple of (pre-existing) join tables.
example:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :stores_teas
   has_many :teas, through: :stores_teas
end

class Tea < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stores_teas
  has_many :stores, through: :stores_teas
end

class StoresTeas < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :tea
end
```

When I try to call something like `store.teas` I am receiving an error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Store::StoresTea
from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:158:in `compute_type'
```

I have set up relationships like this many times before in other projects, but I have always created the tables via a rails migration, not loaded from a `sql` file that also creates the tables. What else do I need to do to map the relationships?

Comment: Are there any nested folders in `app/models`? Do any of the tables for these classes have a column named `type`?

Comment: other than the `concerns` folder which is generated, no.

Comment: And no 'type' column?

Comment: no, there is no type column in any of the tables

Answer (score 1):

Your are in confusion with foreign_keys and ActiveRecord associations.

```
class StoresTeas < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :tea
end
```

Comment: thanks, for that...sorry though, that is a typo. I'll change it in the question.